Unreal Engine 5: Packaging Problem with ThirdPersonCharacter
I got those 2 ERROR Messages when packing an UE 5 project:
LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler] In use pin    no longer exists on node  Reset Orientation and Position . Please refresh node or break links to remove pin. from Source: /Game/PN_GrassLibrary/UE4ThirdPersonTemplate/ThirdPersonBP/Blueprints/ThirdPersonCharacter.ThirdPersonCharacter
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler] Could not find a function named "ResetOrientationAndPosition" in 'ThirdPersonCharacter'
Can someone explain me where to look?
I looked at the Blueprints but just don't know what the problem is, because there is nothing marked with ERROR.
I tried Google and ChatGPT/etc. so get an idea what the problem is.
I used the same adaptions in another project and was able to pack it.
